# Asterisk regular expression : Invalid preceding regular expression

Tags: regex, asterisk

I am trying to verify if inbound CLI matchest one of these patterns:

CLI STARTING WITH:

- +39
- 0039
- 3
- 0[1-9]

So i wrote the following

```
exten => s,n,Set(isita=${REGEX("^(+39|0039|3|0[1-9])" ${cli})})
```

However I am getting this error :

```
 Malformed input REGEX(): Invalid preceding regular expression
```

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: you might need to make your regex a regex like `/^(\+39|0039|3|0[1-9])/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `+`, use this RegEx instead:

```
^(\\+39|0039|3|0[1-9])
```

You can see the error when you <kbd>[**Test it on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d39s)</kbd>

Normally in a RegEx (in JavaScript for example, whre is it enclosed in `/`), you only need one `\`, however when the RegEx is stored in a string (in this case anyway), you need 2 `\`.

If you have one `\`, the string is trying to create a character based on `\+` (like `\n` is a newline). You need the second `\` to state that the first `\` should not be converted.

<kbd>[**New RegEx on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d39v)</kbd>

Comment: Sadly doesn't work...still get  func_strings.c:977 regex: Malformed input REGEX(): Invalid preceding regular expression

Comment: @AaronUllal Try `\\+`?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is correct, but use of REGEXP inside dialplan is not so nice idea. Dialplan itself is regexp, it have form for do regexp based on cli

```
exten => _s/_39.,n,Noop(do something for cli starting with 39)
```

So it more asterisk-way use dialplan, not regexp.